# Compile CoffeeScript in the browser with extras/coffee-script.js

Tags: coffeescript

I would like to create a simple demo page that compiles CoffeeScript in the browser with the [extras/coffee-script.js](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js). However, when I add this source and write my CoffeeScript within my text/coffeescript tags it is compiled in a closure so I don't have access to the CoffeeScript functions in the browser console.

In order to do so, I would need to do

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  window.learning = ->
    "I am learning coffeescript"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

This is not ideal for my presentation. I would like to add the bare = true option so that I have access to the functions in browser console. Where in the [extras/coffee-script.js](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js) do I add this option?

Here is the compiled js:

```
(function() {
  window.learning = function() {
    return "I am learning coffeescript";
  };
})
```

I have this example.coffee:

```
learning = ->
  "I am learning coffeescript"
```

Running the compiler from the command line with the following:

```
coffee -c --bare example.coffee
```

It is compiled to this example.js:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
var learning;                                                                   

learning = function() {
  return "I am learning coffeescript";
};
```

This will be globally available from the console.

Answer (score 3):

The below code prints out to the console: *I am learning coffeescript*

Note: *window.learning* is available in the console on the global scope.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.1.2/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
window.learning = ->
  "I am learning coffeescript"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(window.learning()); }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Where ever you call the `CoffeeScript.compile` function, you can pass in the `--bare` option, much like the command line:

```
CoffeeScript.compile(source, { bare: true });
```

If you look in the minified source, at the end you will see this:

```
CoffeeScript.run(a.innerHTML,s)
```

Where `a` is the `<script>` element, (so `a.innerHTML` is the source) and `s` is the options, which is then passed through run into `compile`:

```
CoffeeScript.run = function (e,t){return null==t&&(t={}),t.bare=!0,Function(compile(e,t))()}
```

As you can see, `t.bare` is set to `!0` (aka `true`), so `bare` is already set!

Comment: I never actually call the CoffeeScript.compile. The coffee-script.js handles that all for me. I am not sure where I need to put the bare = true option in order to get the learning function to be global and accessible from the console.